# firebase xcode - App does not exist error Unity

Tags: ios, firebase, unity-game-engine

Let's get to the point.

I'm building game for iOS using Unity and Firebase as Database. I want to test it on simulator and when I run it, the app running properly but no with back-end.

When I checking the debug navigator, there is some warning that say

> NAMEAPPS[9744:319182] 5.9.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000007] App does not exist.
>   2018-11-21 19:02:04.657011+0530 NAMEAPPS[9744:319856] ERROR: 
>   Database::GetInstance(https://name-apps.firebaseio.com/): nil FIRApp instance passed to databaseForApp.
>   Database::GetInstance(https://name-apps.firebaseio.com/): nil FIRApp instance passed to databaseForApp.
>   UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)

Could anyone tell me what's happening ? Cause I have no idea...

Comment: check if you are building for simulator or for device from Unity IDE

Comment: I already set it for simulator...